# Having trouble with implementing a system that detects if an input is a integer or not

Tags: java, input, integer

I'm trying to make a system that asks the user how many times they want a phrase to be repeated and then it checks if the answer is an integer or a string. The program works well when I don't try to implement this system and leave it just at asking the phrase and how many times it should be repeated but it falls appart when I try to check if the amount of times is an integer or not.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Phrase {
    public static Scanner phraseScan = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static Scanner amountScan = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main (String[] args ) {

        System.out.println("What phrase do you want repeated?");
        String phrase = phraseScan.nextLine();
        int phraseLoops = 0;

        System.out.println("How many " + phrase + "s" + " do you want?");
        int desiredPhraseLoops = amountScan.nextInt();

        for (;;) {
            if (!amountScan.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Integers only please");
                amountScan.next();

            }
            desiredPhraseLoops = amountScan.nextInt();
            if (desiredPhraseLoops >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Valid amount!");
                continue;
            } else {
                break;

            }
        }



        System.out.println(desiredPhraseLoops + " " + phrase + "s coming your way!");

        do {
            System.out.println(phrase);
            phraseLoops++;

        } while (phraseLoops != desiredPhraseLoops);

        System.out.println("You printed " + phraseLoops + " " + phrase + "s" );
    }
}
```

What I've tried:

```
try {
          desiredPhraseLoops = amountScan.nextInt();

        } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
            System.out.println("This is not an integer.");
        } 

          if (!amountScan.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Good.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter an Integer please.");
        }
```

Any time I tried anything, it would ask which phrase I wanted and how many times I wanted it repeated. And then the program just stopped afterward, no matter if I put in an integer or a string, it just didnt give me any other prompts.

The output is this:

What phrase do you want repeated?
Test
How many Tests do you want?
3

And that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, just use one Scanner object. You don't need more than that for keyboard input.

If you like, you can just stick with the **Scanner#nextLine()** method, for example:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 

String phrase = "";
while (phrase.equals("")) {
    System.out.println("What phrase do you want repeated?");
    phrase = userInput.nextLine();
    // VALIDATION: 
    // Was anything other than a empty string (spaces) 
    // or longer than 2 characters supplied?
    if (phrase.trim().equals("") || phrase.length() < 3) {
        // Nope!
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!. Enter a proper phrase!");
        phrase = "";
    }
    // Yes, allow the prompt loop to exit.
}

String phraseLoopsNumber = "";
while (phraseLoopsNumber.equals("")) {
    System.out.println("How many " + phrase + "s" + " do you want?");
    phraseLoopsNumber = userInput.nextLine();
    // VALIDATION: 
    // Did the User supply a string representation of an integer value? 
    if (!phraseLoopsNumber.matches("\\d+")) {
        // Nope!
        System.out.println("Invalid Input (" + phraseLoopsNumber + ")! An integer value is expected!");
        phraseLoopsNumber = "";
    }
    // Yes he/she/it did...Allow prompt loop to exit.
}

int numberOfLoops = Integer.parseInt(phraseLoopsNumber);

// Do what you have to do with the desired number of loops contained
// within the numberOfLoops integer variable.
```

In the above code, the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method was used along with a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx). The `"\\d"` expression passed to the **matches()** method checks to see if the string it is working against contains all (1 or more) digits.

If however you're hell bent on using the **Scanner#nextInt()** method then you can do it this way:

```
int numberOfLoops = -1;
while (numberOfLoops == -1) {
    System.out.println("How many " + phrase + "'s" + " do you want?");
    // Trap any input errors against the Scanner.nextInt() method... 
    // This would be a form of validation.
    try {
        numberOfLoops = userInput.nextInt();
        // Consume the newline from ENTER key in case a nextLine() prompt is next.
        userInput.nextLine(); 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input! An integer value is expected!");
        // Consume the newline from ENTER key in case a nextLine() prompt is next.
        // The first one above would of been skipped past if nextInt() threw an exception.
        userInput.nextLine(); 
        numberOfLoops = -1;
        continue;  // continue loop so as to re-prompt
    }
    // Further Validation: 
    // Did the User supply a number greater than 0? 
    if (numberOfLoops < 1 ) {
        // Nope!
        System.out.println("Invalid Input (" + numberOfLoops + ")! A value 1 or greater is expected!");
        numberOfLoops = -1; 
    }
    // Yes he/she did...Allow prompt loop to exit.
}
// Do what you have to do with the desired number of loops contained
// within the numberOfLoops integer variable.
```

Comment: Thanks, both methods worked for me. However, I don't quite understand why the number of loops begins with -1 in the second method, rather than starting from 0?

Comment: Just a habit. Usually 0 is a valid and desired value but in this particular case it is not and therefore can be used instead of -1.